# Is there a way to download files matching a pattern trough SFTP on shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

I'm trying to download multiple files trough SFTP on a linux server using

```
sftp -o IdentityFile=key <user>@<server><<END
    get -r folder
    exit
END
```

which will download all contents on a folder. It appears that `find` and `grep` are invalid commands, so are for loops.

I need to download files having a name containing a string e.g.

> test_0.txt
>
> test_1.txt
>
> but no file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the `-r` switch? Are there really any subdirectories in the `folder`? You do not mention that.

If there are no subdirectories, you can use a simple `get` with a file mask:

```
cd folder
get *test*
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you required to use `sftp`? A tool like `rsync` that operates over `ssh` has flexible include/exclude options.  For example:

```
rsync -a <user>@<server>:folder/ folder/ \
  --include='test_*.txt' --exclude='*.txt'
```

This requires `rsync` to be installed on the remote system, but that's very common these days.  If `rsync` isn't available, you could do something similar using `tar`:

```
ssh <user>@<server> tar -cf- folder/ | tar -xvf- --wildcards '*/test_*.txt'
```

This tars up all the files remotely, but then only extracts files matching your target pattern on the receiving side.